# C# Crm 2011 caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I wrote code that application is written by c# form application.crm is running with ssl.

```
      ClientCredentials credential = new ClientCredentials(); 
      credential.Windows.ClientCredential = new 
      System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"); 
      Uri organizationUri = new Uri("https://serverAdress/Orgname/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
      Uri homeRealUri = null;
      serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProx
(organizationUri, homeRealUri, credential, null);
                                serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
```

And also i tried tihs version.

```
>  ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials(); 
>     Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName ="<username>"; 
>     Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password ="<password>";
```

It dont throw any exception,but serviceProxy can't authenticated.How to fix?
Any suggestion.

Comment: Does your user have appliation level permissions?

Comment: I know it may be stating the obvious here, but is the user you are attempting to connect to the CRM service as actually a CRM user (on the same domain for example) with the right permissions? The code above looks ok in terms of how one might connect to the CRM service.

Comment: @PhilipRich,that application running on installed crm in server,user have admin rights.

Comment: @KennethIto,user have applicaton level permissions.

Comment: i found problem is when i access with https,user is not authenticated,but i access with just http,user is authenticated.How to solve this situation,@KennethIto,@Philip Rich

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here's my suggestion.

Take a look at the sample code provided here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx

Simply change the following entries to suit your needs

```
    private String _discoveryServiceAddress = "https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc";
    private String _organizationUniqueName = "OrganizationUniqueName";
    // Provide your user name and password.
    private String _userName = "username@mydomain.com";
    private String _password = "password";

    // Provide domain name for the On-Premises org.
    private String _domain = "mydomain";
```

And the console app should print out: Logged on user is "Firstname" "Lastname". Then you can take the OrganizationServiceProxy from:

```
using (OrganizationServiceProxy organizationProxy =
                GetProxy<IOrganizationService, OrganizationServiceProxy>(orgServiceManagement, credentials))
```

and use it.